# C# Execute another program on button click

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Form application. I want to execute another program that is in the same directory with a button click. I only need this code to execute another program.

I have the following code:

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    private void buttonRunScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start = 
                                        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\Scripts\XLXS-CSV.exe";
    }
```

How can I make this work properly? It is not doing anything right now.

Comment: Try to search SO, there are many good questions and answers on the same subject!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why are u using a ProcessStartInfo, you need a Process

```
Process notePad = new Process();    
notePad.StartInfo.FileName   = "notepad.exe";
notePad.StartInfo.Arguments = "ProcessStart.cs"; // if you need some
notePad.Start();
```

This should work ;)

Comment: Properties .HasExited and .ExitCode may be useful.

Answer (score 5):

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\Scripts\XLXS-CSV.exe";
Process.Start(start);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Process yourProcess = new Process();
yourProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Scripts\XLXS-CSV.exe";

yourProcess.Start();
```

You missed to call the Start method and to use the Process class. :)