# c# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2019
I created "Windows Form App"
Target Framework: I have tried .NET core 3.1 and .NET 5.0

I wanted to a creat a program, which has a button, and if the user clicks on it, it opens an .exe, .txt, .docx.
I created a Button with the help of toolbox, double clicked it and i wrote the following code:
System.Diagnostic.Process.Start(@"c:\Users*profilename*\Desktop\asd.txt");
/*asd.txt is just a created txt, with no content in it.

The program runs and if i click on the button, i get the following message:
**"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'"**

I am using Windows 10 Pro 1909

I have already tried the following:
1, Project-->Project Properties-->Build-->Platform Targeted. I set it x64, x86, Any CPU, none of them helped me.
2, I have tried running the program outside of visual studio, it started, but when i clicked on the button, got error message.
3, Updated the windows.
4, Reinstalled the visual studio.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I believe you have the wrong idea about the execution of another program as your code is trying to launch a txt but you have not specified what program handles this task. Have a look at this answer as it might give you a better idea of how to execute a process https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948328/c-sharp-execute-another-program-on-button-click/15948382 in your case the argument would be the file you are trying to open with notepad

Comment: @ArmandoBracho doing `Process.Start("someFile.pdf")` will open said file with the associated application, as if you would double click it in the file explorer, so the problem is something else

Comment: Armando Bracho: I have tried the ideas in the link, none of them helped me unfortunatelly. The message what i get when im running the program outside of Visual Studio is the following: "Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignote the error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately. The specified executable is not valid application for this OS platform"

Comment: I have found the solution. First:If anyone has this kind of problem, try the solutions what i listed in my post.
Secound: When i created a new project i created "Windows Forms App" but i should have created "Windows Forms App(.NET Framework)" I dont know the difference between the two, but with "Windows Forms App(.NET Framework)" the program runs smoothly, with no problem